# Scope of JQuery in a loop?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm working on a project in PHP and a little bit of JQuery.
Im trying to get patients from a database, present them as a table, and then as you hover over on of the rows of the table, it will pop up with a new window showing the patient's health record.
Something like that:

[image]

I give every row in the table an id dynamically since I dont know how many rows I am going to have, like that:

```
echo "<tr id=\"patient" .$count. "\" class=\"trying\">
```

and I increment i by one in every iteration.
However, when I try to use the JQuery, I'm having a problem with accessing each id. I tried to do this:

```
    var count = div.textContent;
    for(var i=0;i<count;i++){
//alert(i);
 $("#patient"+i).mouseover(function() {
     $("#des" +i).show();
 }).mouseout(function() {
     $("#des" +i).hide();
 });
}
```

But even though the loop does run, it just doesn't work (Im guessing because of scope issues). 
Any ideas or recommendation on what I can do to solve this problem?
Thanks a lot

Comment: You need to bind event by class `trying`

Comment: Define "doesn't work".  What *does* it do?  When you debug, how does it fail?  Why are you "guessing because of scope issues"?  What indication do you have for that?  Why are you binding so many mouseover events in the first place?  Why not just do it once for a selector which targets all of the elements you want to target?

Comment: infamous for loop

Comment: count? dont they have their own id they can use?